# SQL - Get one of each in a join

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I've got 2 tables. Table A and B.

Table A has an id and some data which isn't important for the question.
Table B has an id and an A_id. The last one is used to combine the 2 of them. There can be either multiple rows with the same A_id, only 1 or none at all.

I need a query which will do the following:

1. Get only 1 of each row from table A
2. Join table B into it
3. No duplicates from table A

I know it might sound complicated, so here is an example

Table A

```
id other info
 1 ...
 2 ...
 3 ...
 4 ...
```

Table B

```
id A_id
 1    2
 2    3
 3    3
 4    3
```

Output

```
 A.id other info B.id A_id
    1 ...        NULL  NULL
    2 ...           1     2   
    3 ...           2     3   
    4 ...        NULL  NULL
```

So, even though there are multiple rows in table B of which A_id is 3, I only need the one of them. And even though there is no row in table B of which the A_id is 1 or 4, I still need both of them to show up.

This is as clear as I can possibly describe my question, please give feedback on how I can improve this question.

Comment: You should specify the database by using an appropriate tag.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The link you send seems to be offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thank you for Gordon Linoff for pushing me in the right direction. The initial answer was:

```
select A.*,
       (select count(B.A_id) from B where B.A_id = A.id)
from A
```

I'm sorry for not telling this in my question, but all I actually needed was to get every row from A and at the same time check if there was any row in table B which had the same value in A_id as the A.id had.

This query counts all rows which have the same value of A_id as A.id.

To be clear, the output will give:

```
 A.id other info count
    1 ...        0
    2 ...        1 
    3 ...        3  
    4 ...        0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select max(b.id) from b where b.a_id = a.id)
from a;
```

Comment: (I *think* the op wants the min)

Comment: Even though I don't know exactly what's going on between the brackets, this didn't do what I want it to do

Comment: @VellosFree . . . What do you want it to do?  Does using `min()` instead of `max()` do what you really want?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now but it seems that you want something like this

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.A_ID
```

UPDATE:

```
WITH tmp AS (
SELECT MIN(ID) ID FROM B GROUP BY A_id  
)
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM B
INNER JOIN tmp ON B.Id = tmp.ID
RIGHT JOIN A ON A.Id = B.A_Id
```

Comment: No, this will cause duplicates of table A

Comment: Give me a moment to check it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database supports ANSI SQL and when there are multiple rows in B you want the last one based on ID:

```
with lastB (B_Id) as (
  select max(id) from tableB group by A_id 
),
BRows as (
select * from tableB 
    where Id in (select B_Id from lastB)
) 
select a.field1, a.field2, a.fieldN, 
   b.field1, b.field2, b.fieldN
from tableA a
left join BRows b on a.Id = b.A_Id
```

EDIT: Oops. You edited your question and wnat the first one. Then simply make max(), min().

```
with lastB (B_Id) as (
  select min(id) from tableB group by A_id 
),
BRows as (
select * from tableB 
    where Id in (select B_Id from lastB)
) 
select a.field1, a.field2, a.fieldN, 
   b.field1, b.field2, b.fieldN
from tableA a
left join BRows b on a.Id = b.A_Id
```

EDIT: Here is the MS SQL sample I promised for:

```
DECLARE @tableA TABLE ( id INT, other VARCHAR(10) );
DECLARE @tableB TABLE
    (
      id INT ,
      A_Id INT ,
      other VARCHAR(10)
    );

INSERT  @tableA
        ( id, other )
VALUES  ( 1, 'v1' ),
        ( 2, 'v2' ),
        ( 3, 'v3' ),
        ( 4, 'v4' ); 

INSERT  @tableB
        ( id, A_Id, other )
VALUES  ( 1, 2, 'v21' ),
        ( 2, 3, 'v31' ),
        ( 3, 3, 'v32' ),
        ( 4, 3, 'v33' );

WITH    fromB ( B_Id )
          AS ( SELECT   MIN(id)
               FROM     @tableB
               GROUP BY A_Id
             ),
        BRows
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     @tableB
               WHERE    id IN ( SELECT  B_Id
                                FROM    fromB )
             )
    SELECT  a.id AS A_Id ,
            a.other AS A_Other ,
            b.id AS B_Id ,
            b.other AS B_Other
    FROM    @tableA a
            LEFT JOIN BRows b ON a.id = b.A_Id;
```

Result:

```
A_Id A_Other B_Id B_Other
1    v1      NULL NULL
2    v2      1    v21
3    v3      2    v31
4    v4      NULL NULL
```

Comment: Could you make a code of the edit? I don't exactly know what you mean by max(), min() and how I can implement that within the code you wrote

Comment: With just the fields you provide you are overlooking what would happen to additional data from B. If B only had those columns then this code would seem to be longer than needed (in real life B has more columns). Wish you gave us some meaningful data. Anyway, I am going to add an SQL server sample.